# Multisig wallets cannot execute functions on another contract because it requires an EOA

Tags: solidity, nft

I want my smart contract to block other contracts from minting an NFT and it has:

```
require(msg.sender == tx.origin)
```

But this doesnt allow multisigs to mint

What should i do?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't block other contracts. At least for the following reasons:

1. Multisigs
2. Contract wallets (account abstraction), such as Argent
3. In general some features may require a relaying contract. Such as meta transactions.

Furthermore, it would be really difficult to try to whitelist just one type of contracts, since detecting contract 'types' is quite difficult.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! But what if its like a NFT contract and then people could create a contract that generates multiple contracts and this will bypass the minting limit. This happened with Adidas NFT and someone minted 300 NFTs in one transaction.

Comment: You simply need to design your contract in a way that the used limits make sense and can't be bypassed that easily.

Comment: Yes but that would require this:

require(msg.sender == tx.origin)

Comment: No, I mean think it differently. You simply shouldn't try to add that kind of limitations. Or then just google how others have done it (successfully). I'm really not an expert in preventing someone from gaming a minting contract.

Comment: Ok, thanks, appreciate it!